# Straight rsync with intermediate SSH host

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

There's a bunch of great tips here regarding using rsync with "proxy" host, but all I found assume there's SSH server everywhere.

What I have is:

- host A - rsync client, SSH client (Linux), access to B
- host B - SSH server (Linux), access to C
- host C - rsync server (it's actually a Windows machine with Deltacopy server)

How should rsync command look so that it opens SSH connection to host B and remote tunnel to host C, from which the files will be taken?

(hope I gave clear explanation of what I need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the rsync (Deltacopy) server on C listens on the TCP port 873 and you can reach it from B. If so, this becomes the general problem of reaching a TCP port of C from A, when A cannot reach C directly, but can `ssh` to B which can reach C.

Use local port forwarding:

```
# on A
ssh -NL 8873:C_seen_from_B:873 userB@B_seen_from_A
```

Here `8873` is the local port number, quite arbitrary; `ssh` will listen on this port. I did not use `873` for two reasons:

1. there may be a local rsync server that has already taken the port;
2. you most likely are [not allowed to use a port with number lower than 1024 anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports).

Now if you connect from A to `localhost:8873` then you will reach the port 873 of C. C will see traffic coming in from B. So far there is nothing specific to rsync.

Next invoke `rsync` on A and wherever in the command you need to specify a `LOCATION` on C, use the syntax `rsync://[USER@]HOST[:PORT]/LOCATION` (see "access via rsync daemon" in [`man 1 rsync`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1)), where `HOST` is `localhost` and `PORT` is `8873`.

E.g. if on B you would use `rsync://C_seen_from_B:873/foo/bar`, now on A you should use `rsync://localhost:8873/foo/bar`.

This way `rsync` on A will connect to `localhost:8873` of A where `ssh` listens. The connection will be tunneled via SSH and the SSH server on B will connect to `C_seen_from_B:873` for you. Ultimately the `rsync` invoked on A will talk to the rsync (Deltacopy) server running on C.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I figured out in the meanwhile. A better solution would be to do it in a single command, but I couldn't think of how to do that. Anyway, thanks for the answer!